# Thrown Exception: C# Command text was not set for the command object

Tags: c#, runtime-error

I'm new to C#, only been studying it for a few weeks. I'm writing an application with a windows form from and Access database at the back. I want the details inserted by the user to be added to access database. I've looked through other forums (including on stackoverflow) to get this far, but I keep getting an error thrown at run time stating 'Command text was not set for the command object' (ive highlighted the line it appears on below) which I dont understand and can't get rid of. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks K

```
private void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = 
                "provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;" +
                "data source=C:\\Users\\Documents\\StudentRegistrationDatabase.accdb";

        OleDbConnection myOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand myOleDbCommand = myOleDbConnection.CreateCommand();

        string strSql = @"INSERT INTO StudentDetails ([Forename],[Surname],[CourseName],[DOB],)" + 

            "VALUES('"+txtFirstName.Text +"','" +txtLastName.Text +"','" +txtCourseName.Text +"','"+ txtDOB.Text +"')";


        myOleDbConnection.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, myOleDbConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", txtFirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtLastName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", txtCourseName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtDOB);

        **myOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();**   }
```

Edit:
Thank you all for your replies. When I first started coding this piece, I used the following lines of code:

```
'   {
            string connectionString = 
                "provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;" +
                "data source=C:\\Users\\Botterill\\Documents\\StudentRegistrationDatabase.accdb";

            OleDbConnection myOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand myOleDbCommand = myOleDbConnection.CreateCommand();
myOleDbConnection.Open();
            myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StudentDetails ([Forename],[Surname],[CourseName],[DOB],)" +

             "VALUES('" + txtFirstName.Text + "','" + txtLastName.Text + "','" + txtCourseName.Text + "','" + txtDOB.Text + "')";'
**myOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();**
```

But, on the line in bold I was getting a runtime error saying that there was 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement'.I thought this would be corrected in the changes I made in the first question I posted. Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thanks Kate

Comment: Why do you add parameters that aren't there? If you want to use the `AddWithValue` method you need to provide `@Forename` in your code instead of directly inserting `txtFirstName.Text`

Answer (score 3):

You create `myOleDbCommand` from the connection and then you continue to set up the `cmd` instance with the query text, and then you execute `myOleDbCommand` which doesn't have any command text attached to it.

Which instance of `OleDbCommand` do you really want to use?

Additionally, as @thorarin notes, you should use the named parameters (as in `cmd` example) and not concatenate the strings to create the command text, as you open your application for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Apart from that, it's a good idea to use the named parameters like OP is doing with `cmd`, but the SQL query is not using them. String concatenation is used, with all the risks of SQL injection.

Comment: You are right. it seems that `cmd` stuff was just pasted from somewhere and left there.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Thank you for your reply! Initially when I wrote this bit of code I wrote it differently (as i will edit my question to show) only using myOleDbCommand. However, this also threw and error in the same place at runtime saying that there was missing syntax in the insert into statement. I initially thought i was correcting it by adding the parameters. But i'm really not sure on how to go about it! Kate